# Can I implement an MVC architecture using PHP,Web Services and Stored Procedures

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller

I am trying to move away from a simple PHP/MySQL architecture where I simply do everything on a single layer of PHP and connecting to data on MySQL tables.

MVC is the way to go as I see it but I am unsure how to implement.

My idea is to have an Apache Web Server (httpd) hosting the PHP pages that provide the View. Only that would be on the DMZ of the network.

These would use Web Services implemented either in PHP on a separate (internal) Apache Web Server or using Apache CXF.

Finally the web services would be connecting to the MySQL servers, and I would implement the business logic using stored procedures/functions in the database.

Is my thinking completely flawed here? Is this not MVC at all? Can it be done in a way that it does satisfy the MVC architecture?

Comment: If all business logic is implemented with stored procedures, why would you need a service layer? ;-) in other words, it seems like something only Chuck Norris would be able to pull off.

Comment: All business logic as stored procedures in the database?! Sounds somewhere between impossible, requiring a lot of bending over backwards and/or dogmatism for no reason. Let each system do what it's good at. The database stores data well, PHP or other languages can implement arbitrarily complex rules. Other than that though, sounds like a decent start for decoupling parts.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying while I could use some stored procedures where useful, it would be the web services where most business logic would lie?

Comment: Not that separate servers have intrinsically something to do with MVC though. What you're describing is an n-tier system, which may or may not be built using MVC; perhaps each individual part is or isn't build using MVC.

Comment: Stored procedures are useful for complex, repetitive database operations. Business logic has nothing intrinsically to do with databases. Databases only incidentally persist your data, they do not form the core of your business.

Comment: Yes. That is what I didn't manage to explain well in my question. I guess the question is, can I, and how would I use MVC on this n-tier system. I'd like to think the DB/Stored Procedures function as the model, but I am not too clear on the View and Controllers

Comment: See some previous attempts to clarify what MVC is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15274524/476

Comment: Thanks. It is starting to make a lot of sense. This article also proved useful ; http://criticaltechnology.blogspot.com/2011/09/mvc-in-three-tier-architecture.html